# ProcessBuilder calling commands from wrong /bin

Tags: java, bash, processbuilder

I have a repo on github where I want to pull the latest master branch whenever there is a merge to it from a pull request. I have a springboot app that handles getting that request, and I have a script written out to handle the pulling for me. The springboot app runs this script via ProcessBuilder when the event occurs, but I keep getting "command not found" errors from the commands inside the script (sudo for running command as a different user and git, specifically).

I'm running Pop!_OS, an Ubuntu based distro of Linux, and I'm using Eclipse as my IDE.

I've checked to see what user the program thinks it is, and it echos as my user. I've made sure the path includes things like `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, etc. I copied my PATH as an environment arg in eclipse. I've tried using absolute paths to commands in the script like `/bin/git`, or `/usr/bin/git`. None of that has worked. I decided to do `ls` to see what files the ProcessBuilder saw from it's perspective in `/bin` and `/usr/bin` and noticed that it seems to be missing files that I can see, like git, and I assume that's why it apparently cannot be found.

User echoed when ProcessBuilder runs script: `evan`

Path echoed when ProcessBuilder runs script: `/home/evan/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/srv/minecraft/bin`

Error given from ProcessBuilder: `/srv/minecraft/bin/bashpull: line 38: git: command not found`

Does anyone know why ProcessBuilder seems to not see the same files as the user it thinks it is vs. when I am the user I can see those files?

Example - Looking for git in `/bin`:

**ProcessBuilder**
[ProcessBuilder /bin ls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRS8P.png)

**Me**
[My user /bin ls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ieMW.png)

[EDIT]
I searched my file system for one of the commands in the screenshot I posted that my ProcessBuilder sees and have found this my ProcessBuilder seems to be in on of these folders for some reason:

[Directory path where ProcessBuilder is looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbFa7.png)

Here are all the environment args set on my ProcessBuilder. I'm imagining there might be something here causing the ProcessBuilder to be relegated to a different directory for running things.

```
Key = PATH, Value = /home/evan/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/srv/minecraft/bin
Key = LC_MEASUREMENT, Value = en_US.UTF-8
Key = XAUTHORITY, Value = /run/user/1000/Xauthority
Key = INVOCATION_ID, Value = aa620309e8eb40119f6fccf9759a9f47
Key = XMODIFIERS, Value = @im=ibus
Key = LC_TELEPHONE, Value = en_US.UTF-8
Key = XDG_DATA_DIRS, Value = /app/share:/usr/share:/usr/share/runtime/share:/run/host/user-share:/run/host/share
Key = GDMSESSION, Value = pop
Key = MANDATORY_PATH, Value = /usr/share/gconf/pop.mandatory.path
Key = LC_TIME, Value = en_US.UTF-8
Key = PAPERSIZE, Value = letter
Key = GTK_IM_MODULE, Value = ibus
Key = DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS, Value = unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
Key = PS1, Value = [ $FLATPAK_ID \W]\$ 
Key = DEFAULTS_PATH, Value = /usr/share/gconf/pop.default.path
Key = XDG_CACHE_HOME, Value = /home/evan/.var/app/org.eclipse.Java/cache
Key = XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP, Value = pop:GNOME
Key = JOURNAL_STREAM, Value = 8:44922
Key = SSH_AGENT_PID, Value = 3053
Key = LC_PAPER, Value = en_US.UTF-8
Key = SESSION_MANAGER, Value = local/pop-os:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/3208,unix/pop-os:/tmp/.ICE-unix/3208
Key = USERNAME, Value = evan
Key = ALSA_CONFIG_PATH, Value = /usr/share/alsa/alsa-flatpak.conf
Key = LOGNAME, Value = evan
Key = GST_PLUGIN_SYSTEM_PATH, Value = /app/lib/gstreamer-1.0:/usr/lib/extensions/gstreamer-1.0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0
Key = PWD, Value = /home/evan
Key = MANAGERPID, Value = 2266
Key = MATHEMATICA_HOME, Value = /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.1
Key = LANGUAGE, Value = en_US:en
Key = GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS, Value = JS ERROR;JS LOG
Key = SHELL, Value = /bin/sh
Key = LC_ADDRESS, Value = en_US.UTF-8
Key = GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE, Value = /home/evan/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/applications/org.eclipse.Java.desktop
Key = AT_SPI_BUS_ADDRESS, Value = unix:path=/run/user/1000/at-spi-bus
Key = GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID, Value = this-is-deprecated
Key = GTK_MODULES, Value = gail:atk-bridge:appmenu-gtk-module
Key = ALSA_CONFIG_DIR, Value = /usr/share/alsa
Key = XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP, Value = pop
Key = SHLVL, Value = 0
Key = LC_IDENTIFICATION, Value = en_US.UTF-8
Key = LC_MONETARY, Value = en_US.UTF-8
Key = OXYGEN_DISABLE_INNER_SHADOWS_HACK, Value = 1
Key = QT_IM_MODULE, Value = ibus
Key = XDG_CONFIG_DIRS, Value = /app/etc/xdg:/etc/xdg
Key = LANG, Value = en_US.UTF-8
Key = XDG_SESSION_TYPE, Value = x11
Key = FLATPAK_SANDBOX_DIR, Value = /home/evan/.var/app/org.eclipse.Java/sandbox
Key = DISPLAY, Value = :99.0
Key = GI_TYPELIB_PATH, Value = /app/lib/girepository-1.0
Key = LC_NAME, Value = en_US.UTF-8
Key = XDG_SESSION_CLASS, Value = user
Key = _, Value = /usr/bin/dbus-update-activation-environment
Key = FLATPAK_ID, Value = org.eclipse.Java
Key = XDG_DATA_HOME, Value = /home/evan/.var/app/org.eclipse.Java/data
Key = LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR, Value = 0
Key = GDK_CORE_DEVICE_EVENTS, Value = 1
Key = GPG_AGENT_INFO, Value = /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
Key = DESKTOP_SESSION, Value = pop
Key = USER, Value = evan
Key = XDG_CONFIG_HOME, Value = /home/evan/.var/app/org.eclipse.Java/config
Key = XDG_MENU_PREFIX, Value = gnome-
Key = GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID, Value = 5636
Key = QT_ACCESSIBILITY, Value = 1
Key = WINDOWPATH, Value = 2
Key = LC_NUMERIC, Value = en_US.UTF-8
Key = GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT, Value = stderr
Key = SSH_AUTH_SOCK, Value = /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
Key = GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE, Value = pop
Key = XDG_RUNTIME_DIR, Value = /run/user/1000
```

Comment: You are looking at two different directories. Is your app running under Docker or chroot or similar that provides a different view of the file system?

Comment: Definitely no docker. I am running the springboot app from eclipse for debugging, so I'm not sure if that imposes some restrictions or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments confirmed, my ProcessBuilder was indeed looking in a different directory. I run a distro of Linux called Pop_OS! and it's app store had Eclipse available as a flatpak.

As a security feature Flatpak sandboxes apps on its own, relegating them to their own slice of the file system and that restriction is what was causing me my issue.

I uninstalled the Flatpak version of Eclipse, and reinstalled it using the eclipse installer from their website. After I did that the issue was fixed. I was able to run my script and the there were no more "command not found" issue.